# Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I'm new on Jest + Enzyme and I been doing some test in my app, everything was good till I try to test onPress event in one of my components that renders a ScrollView that has a ListItem inside. The error is: `Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Below is my code:

**List.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, Image, View, ScrollView, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Button, Card } from 'react-native-elements'
import {observer, inject} from 'mobx-react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

@inject('ItemStore')
@observer
export default class List extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        itemsSelected: [],
    }
  }

  displayItem(item, index){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;             
    this.props.ItemStore.ItemStore.itemSelected(item);
    navigate("OtherComp", {'index': index});
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <ScrollView>
                {
                    this.props.ItemStore.items.length ?
                    this.props.ItemStore.items.map((item, i) => (
                        <ListItem roundAvatar avatar = {{uri: item.photo_uri}} 
                                  title = {item.name}
                                  key = {i}
                                  onPress = {this.displayItem.bind(this, item, i)} 
                                  onLongPress = {this.setitem.bind(this, i)}
                                  containerStyle = {{ backgroundColor: this.state.itemsSelected.indexOf(i) >= 0 ? "#f1f1f1" : "#ffffff"}}
                        />
                    )) : undefined
                }   
        </ScrollView>
    );
 }

}
```

**List.test.js**

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import MyList from '../../components/list/List';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

const ItemStore = require('../../stores/ItemStore').default;

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('ItemList', () => {
it('click list item', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyList ItemStore={ItemStore.ItemStore} />)        
    const render = wrapper.dive();
    const displayItem = sinon.spy(MyList, "displayItem");
    render.find(ListItem).forEach(child => {
        child.simulate('onPress');
    });
    expect(displayItem.calledOnce).toBe(true);
 });
});
```

I'm using multiple stores that's why the invoke it's `store.store`

Comment: In which file/line is that list reference? There is no a single reference to that variable in your posted code.

Comment: I updated the post it was items instead of list and is in this line `this.props.ItemStore.items.length`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

this.props.ItemStore.items.length

Be..

this.props.ItemStore.ItemStore.items.length ?

Comment: I did that but no results, the problem seems like it's on the test, the application runs great but when I run the test that error appears and I tried with mount but same result